# if statement to mathematical addition gives answer zero in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

' total service till retirement

```
    retirement = Me.DateTimePicker2.Value
    appointment = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim workingTime As TimeSpan = retirement - appointment
    Dim yearVal As Double = workingTime.TotalDays / 365
    Dim years = CInt(Math.Floor(yearVal))
    Dim monthVal = (workingTime.TotalDays - years * 365) / 30
    Dim months As Int32 = CInt(Math.Floor(monthVal))
    Dim dayVal = workingTime.TotalDays - (years * 365 + months * 30)
    Dim days As Int32 = CInt(Math.Floor(dayVal))
    Dim result = $" {years} years {months} months & {days} Days"

    tservice.Clear()
    tservice.Text = result

    '   Pay reckonable for pension.
    reckonable = Val(lastpay.Text) + Val(increment.Text)

    '17.    Service on the date of retirement. rounded off
    If months > 5 Then
        totalyear = (Val(years) + 1)

    End If


    '1. PENSION:-17760x26x7/300=Rs. 10774.40
    tpension.Clear()
    pension = (Val(reckonable) * Val(totalyear) * 7 / 300)
    tpension.Text = pension
```

i need that answer should not be zero but due to  **totalyear**  a integer variable inside if statement gives zero i want it to add a value 1 if num of months is greater than 5 kindly help me.

Comment: If months <=5, where do you assign totalyear then?

Comment: here in this code Val( **totalyear** ) in pension formula pension gives an answer zero    `pension = (Val(reckonable) * Val( **totalyear** ) * 7 / 300)`

Comment: No, there you are *using* that value, but what *is* the value (where did you *assign* it) when the code doesn't come into your `if`? I guess you need to add an `Else` and do a `totalyear=year` there

Comment: thankyou it was just else missing in the statement